# Script for update

Tags: linux, bash, scripting, grep, updatedb

I have a script used for update :

```
OLD="int 10"
NEW="int 20"
i=0
DPATH="/home"

for f in $DPATH
do
    sed -i "s/$OLD/$NEW/g" $f
    let i++
echo "modified:" $f
done
```

what i need according to my old value have the path where i can change OLD to NEW (for update)

Comment: Would you like to rename the files in `DPATH` or modify the contents of certain files in `DPATH`. Some examples would help.

Comment: i want to modify the contents of txt file in DPATH my value OLD is in many txt file in DPATH so i want to have this path to do the update .Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

You can use this script:

```
#!/bin/bash
OLD="int 10"
NEW="int 20"

for file in /home/a/*; do
  [[ -f $file ]] && sed -i "s/$OLD/$NEW/g" "$file" && echo "modified: $file"
done
```

Comment: i have this  error **sed: couldn't edit /home/a/b: not a regular file**                   I think the problem that they can't have the subdirectory

Comment: @toto: Check my edits..you were getting the eroor because `/home/a/b` is a direcotiry..now we are considering regular files only..